Google Analytics API: How to run a report for AlphaAnalyticsDataClient?
The Issue
I cannot figure out how to run a report in the Google Analytics API for AlphaAnalyticsDataClient Alpha.
There is seemingly no equivalent for client.run_report for Alpha. What would be the equivalent for this in Alpha?
Context
In the beta, this could be done simply with:
client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
request = RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[Dimension(name="date")],
    metrics=[Metric(name="events")],
    date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date='2024-10-26', end_date='2024-10-26')],
    dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
        and_group=FilterExpressionList(
            expressions=[
                FilterExpression(
                    filter=Filter(
                        field_name="customEvent:day",
                        in_list_filter=Filter.InListFilter(
                            values=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'])))
                            ])),
        limit=limit,
        offset=offset)

response = client.run_report(request)

I tried to find the similar phrase which was report_task instead of run_report but it was not correct.

why use alpha when there is beta?

Only alpha has the sampling_level available to get unsampled results.
